# Displaying a List of Videos From My YouTube Channel

Tags: c#, api, youtube

I am trying to display a list of my videos from my YouTube channel in C#, but I can't.

When I run the program, I get such an error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

---

```
YouTubeRequestSettings settings = new YouTubeRequestSettings("my app name",
            "my devkey",
            "my email", "my password");
        YouTubeRequest request = new YouTubeRequest(settings);
 string feedUrl = "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default/uploads";

        Feed<Video> videoFeed = request.Get<Video>(new Uri(feedUrl));
        foreach (Video entry in videofeed.Entries)
        {
            list.Items.Add(entry);

        }
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like it should be

```
YouTubeRequest settings = new YouTubeRequest(ayarlar);
```

otherwise you're trying to pass the not-yet instantiated `settings` variable as a parameter to the `YouTubeRequest` constructor.

**Update from comment**

Since you want a global variable, don't create a new instance here and use the existing one like this

```
//earlier code
string feedUrl = "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default/uploads";

//the Feed<Video> has been removed because you want to use the global variable
videoFeed = request.Get<Video>(new Uri(feedUrl));
foreach (Video entry in videofeed.Entries)
{
   list.Items.Add(entry);
}
```

Comment: exactly this line :Feed<Video> videoFeed = istek.Get<Video>(new Uri(feedUrl));

Comment: Is `istek` supposed to be `request`?

Comment: and i forgot to write , there is a variable toppest of the page, called  "Feed<Video> videofeed;"

Comment: Do you want the `videofeed` in the code above to be the same as the one at the top of the page? If so, try using this `videoFeed = request.Get<Video>(new Uri(feedUrl));`

Comment: I've updated my answer. You just need to remove the `Feed<Video>` part from the code you posted because that's creating a new instance within that scope. Somewhere else in the code, you're trying to call the `videoFeed` variable that's at the top of your class but since that's different from the one above, it hasn't been instantiated.

Comment: Feed<Video> videoFeed;
            

            string feedUrl = "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default/uploads";

            videoFeed = istek.Get<Video>(new Uri(feedUrl));
            foreach (Video entry in videoFeed.Entries)
            {
                list.Items.Add(entry);


            }

Comment: Run the debugger and check what object is null.

Comment: Thanks for everything, i ve solved the problem , i am very grateful to you for your help

Comment: You're welcome. If my answer helped, you can mark it as answered by clicking on the tick on the left. If it didn't answer your question, you can write the answer yourself and accept that one :)